# Counterexample for convergence of sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $X = \{x \in \mathbb R^{n+1}_+: \sum_{i=1}^{n+1}x_i=1\}$, the $n$-dimensional simplex, $n\geq 2$.

Let $f:X \to X$ such that $f$ is Lipschitz continuous, with Lipschitz constant $L>1$.

Let $(x_t)_t\subset X$ be such that, for some $x_0 \in X$, 
$x_t=\frac{t}{t+1}x_{t-1}+\frac{1}{t+1}f(x_{t-1})$, $t=1,2,...$.

I have 2 questions:

(1) Does $(x_t)_t$ converge?

It seems like these conditions are not sufficient to ensure convergence but I cannot construct a counterexample.

(2) Is it the case that at any limit point $\bar x$, we have $\bar x = f(\bar x)$?

Again this seems false, but I cannot find a counterexample.

Comment: With the coefficients $\frac1{t+1}$ and $\frac1{t+1}$, it doesn't seem that $x_t$ remains in the simplex $X$ (take $t=2$ and $f$ to be the identity function, for example).

Comment: My bad. It is an average, $t/(t+1) x_{t-1} + 1/(t+1)f(x_{t-1})$. Updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing the answer to both questions is "no" (although $n=1$ might be special). Here's an outline of a potential proof for $n=2$:

First, the $2$-simplex is homeomorphic to the closed $2$-ball, and since both spaces are compact, it should be true that Lipschitz functions on the two spaces correspond to each other via pullbacks/pushforwards.

Now on the boundary of the $2$-ball (the circle), the answer to the questions is definitely "no": just take $f$ to be rotation by $\frac\pi2$, say, and interpret $\frac1{t+1}f$ as rotation by $\frac\pi{2(t+1)}$. Then the sequence $(x_t)$ continues to forever circumnavigate the circle, going at logarithmic speed like the harmonic series.

We could try extending this example to the whole disk itself, letting $f$ be rotation by $\frac\pi2$. However, when we use actual addition of vectors rather than the "model" of adding angles only above, I worry that the repeated additions would cause $x_t$ to slowly spiral inwards and converge to the center of the ball.

However, we could instead define $f$ to rotate *and* push points towards the boundary. For example, in polar coordinates, perhaps $f(r,\theta) = (\sqrt r,\theta+\frac\pi8)$. I suspect that with this function (or a modification of it), the sequence $x_t$ would stay near the boundary of the disk and forever travel around the circumference.

(I didn't check whether this $f$ is Lipschitz near the center of the disk; however, we should be able to arrange for the sequence $x_t$ to be completely contained in the annulus $\{\frac12\le r\le 1\}$, and so the function $f$ can be modified to any Lipschitz function on the disk $\{r\le\frac12\}$.)

Comment: Thank you! This is very insightful.